# Arduino constructor not declared in scope

Tags: c++, class, constructor, arduino

I am trying to get myself familiar with creating classes in Arduino. I have a class which should take 4 different pins as inputs/outputs. 
When I do it with 1 pin it works fine, however when I try to use multiple pins the following error occurs: `_pin1 was not declared in this scope`.

[[image]]

Comment: Don't post your code as image. Post your code directly as text.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce. [This code](http://codepad.org/6lPSxs6h) succesfully compiled with Arduino 1.6.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you posted the real code instead of the image, someone could have noticed.

However that error is simple: you didn't declare `_pin1` anywhere. So simply write `int _pin1;` inside the class declaration.

And... I think that you'll want to get rid of that `_pinl` declaration.. Because everyone can confuse `_pin1` (i.e. PIN ONE) with `_pinl` (i.e. PIN EL), but a computer doesn't...

Comment: Waw I hadn't seen that! Thank you very much guys, you just made my day! :D(Will post as code next time! Thanks for the tip! )

Comment: Then mark the answer as correct ;) (click the green check image on the left)